# Formating multiple mySQL date fields at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 12 timestamp columns and 3 other fields.
I can't change the field type on the timestamp columns.

I need to display all 15 fields to the user as m/d/y.  Is there a way to format them all at the same time without having to apply DATE_FORMAT to each one?
I'd rather not have to do

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(field, '%c/%e/%y') AS field
```

for each one if possible.

I'm using mySQL & PHP and I don't care where the conversion happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple date conversion routine in php such as this:

```
function mysql2table($date) {
    $new = explode("-",$date);
    $a=array ($new[2], $new[1], $new[0]);
return $n_date=implode("-", $a);
}
```

Which I stole from here: http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet736.html#

Then simply loop through your SQL column results checking if the value is a date and converting it.

Comment: Thanks...that what I was thinking, and it helps since I already have a date conversion function I can call on...I was hoping for an all-in-one solution...oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a database layer like MDB2 or PDO, which can convert the types for you? MDB2 has a date type, that displays YYYY-MM-DD format but could easily be turned into m/d/y with strftime and strtotime.

An example of using MDB2:

```
$dsn = "mysql://user@pass/db"; (not sure about DSN format, you might have to poke the MDB2 documentation)
$connection = MDB2::connect ($dsn);
$connection->loadModule ("Extended");
$rows = $connection->getAll ("your query", array ('date', ...), $parameters, array (paramater-types), MDB2_FETCHMODE_OBJECT);

if (MDB2_Driver_Common::isError ($rows)) throw new Exception ("Error!");
else { foreach ($rows as $row) { ...Do something... } }
```

You can find more documentation about using MDB in this way at [MDB2 on InstallationWiki](http://www.installationwiki.org/MDB2#Shortcuts_for_Retrieving_Data). Also there you'll find a list of MDB2 datatypes and what they are mapped to for display values. Also, [Docs for MDB2_Extended](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Extended.html) will be a good source of info.

Edit: Obviously you'll have to use strftime and strtotime on each row separately. If you switch `MDB2_FETCHMODE_OBJECT` to `MDB2_FETCHMODE_ORDERED` or `MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC` above, you can probably use a foreach loop to run strftime and strtotime on all of the rows that need to be reformatted.

Comment: Thanks...I did look PDO - it's just not something I can dig into right now.

Comment: Ah. Well, I hope you have time to look into them, they can make writing code a *lot* easier. MDB2 can even automatically do updates and inserts for you, without you writing a bit of SQL. Probably selects too, though I haven't figured that bit out yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible, the query doesnt know what columns are until it returns the results, you have to tell it to change the formatting for each datetime.

Matt